# Password not accepted on sudo

Tags: sudo

Probably after changing hostname using settings or removing cryptswap, but I have also updated `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.1.1 pop2104.localdomain     pop2104
```

There's no error message, it just keeps asking for my password again and again (like the password is wrong).

```
# from journalctl -r
Nov 08 13:07:34 pop2104 sudo[8413]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [asd]
Nov 08 13:07:34 pop2104 sudo[8413]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed

Nov 08 13:09:14 pop2104 sudo[9093]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory

# from /etc/passwd
asd:x:1000:1000:ASD:/home/asd:/usr/bin/zsh
```

I'm sure the password is correct, because when unlocking the keyring it works fine.

I am using PopOS 21.04.

Comment: That `/etc/hosts` file looks wrong - protocols like `https` have no place there.

Comment: `Couldn't open /etc/securetty` doesn't look good. This file is (on my system) world readable so the message implies you've deleted the file or changed the permissions...?

Comment: Have you changed any of the PAM files in `/etc/pam.d`?

Comment: oh that http is because of copy pasting from reddit XD, lemme edit that @Panki

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/hosts` must be in format:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.1.1 pop2104.localdomain     pop2104
```

No protocols, no brackets

Answer (score 1):

The error messages suggest the PAM authentication module `pam_unix.so` "could not identify password" for the user. That might mean your `/etc/shadow` is somehow corrupted.

Try running `pwck` as root. It will typically output some messages about some system accounts not having a valid home directory: that is normal and can be ignored. But *does it say anything about user `asd`*?

The other error message indicates `/etc/securetty` is missing. Some Linux distributions consider `/etc/securetty` to be no longer useful, while others still have it. Apparently PopOS expects it to be there.

If it has vanished with no apparent reason, then your system may have been (poorly) hacked: the intruder may have been trying to use some exploit to remove `/etc/securetty` and to inject an extra entry to `/etc/shadow`, but it seems the presumed injection attempt to `/etc/shadow` may have been less than successful, if it has broken the file format.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting, booting `rescue` drop to `root` user, and then `passwd asd`, it can sudo now.

Comment: What, you mean there originally wasn't a password for `asd` at all?

Comment: @roaima there is, but suddenly I can't sudo anymore with old password, resetting to new password with the same value as old password btw